# Button to hide a TextView

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener

I've been searching for a solution for this for a while but cannot seem to get one working. There are one or two on here about this subject but I can't seem to get them going. I'm also a novice in Android and while I've been on and off playing with it for a few years, I still understand next to nothing about what I'm writing.

Basically I've got a TextView and a button. Ideally I'd like to put some text in the TextView, press a button it's gone, press the button again and it's back.

I've narrowed it down to needing to understand what findViewById(R.id.button2) does but honestly I'm a bit lost.

I've added my button code but apologies that this is such a noob question

```
public void onClick(Button v){
    TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a couple of issues.  I'm not going to give you the code because that won't really help you learn.  Instead I'll explain things and let you try to figure it out or come back with more explicit questions.

You know that xml file you set using setContentView?  Some of the tags in it had a property android:id="xxxx".  That xxxx is the id of that view, its used so you can find that view in your code.  The findViewById function walks through all the views on screen and finds a view with that id and returns it.  That gives you a reference to the view so you can change it.  For example, you can set its visibility, set its background color, or set an OnClickListener.

So to have a button toggle the visibility of another view, you need to be able to do the following things:

1)Find the view who's visibility you want to change

2)Figure out what its visibility currently is

3)Figure out what you want it to be (the opposite of what it currently is

4)Set that visibility

You need to write a function that does all that.  Then you need to do this

1)Find the button you want to use to change the visibility

2)Tell it to call your function when its pressed.

Figure out how to do each of those steps individually, and you should be able to put it together.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

`findViewById(R.id.button2)` finds the view with the id button2.

You can check inside onClick whether t1 is visible or not (`t1.setVisibility(View.GONE);` not `v.setVisibility(View.GONE);`), and toggle between `View.GONE` and `View.VISIBLE`.

Remember that your findViewById() should have a real id. They are normally set on the activity_name.xml.

You are using a onClick inside a onClick. Personally I recommend setting the listener manually with setOnClickListener.

There's a lot of work for you, start with these [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=taSwS5rhtmc&nohtml5=False). Keep trying and try to understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you need a toogle button feature, here is a piece of code.

Important: you must pay heed to @GabeSechan and @SkyDriver2500 answers.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
    //your other code

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    final TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            t1.setVisibility(t1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if the code will help you now. But just in case, here it is

```
            final boolean[] isTvVisible = {false};
            final TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
            t1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (isTvVisible[0]) {
                        t1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        isTvVisible[0] = false;
                    } else {
                        t1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        isTvVisible[0] = true;
                    }
                }
            });
```